# NameError: name 'athena' is not defined , when importing athena query function from another jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, amazon-athena

My query_distinct_data() function executes successfully when run.
But when I try to import the query_distinct_data() using Jupyter notebook from my function page map_distinct_data on to my main page I get the following error.

```
NameError: name 'athena' is not defined
```

Below is my main page below

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from datetime import date
import boto3
import time
import geopandas
import folium

from ipynb.fs.full.qld_2 import qld_data
from ipynb.fs.full.vic_2 import vic_data
from ipynb.fs.full.put_to_s3_bucket import put_to_s3_bucket
from ipynb.fs.full.map_distinct_data import query_distinct_data
from ipynb.fs.full.map_distinct_data import distinct_data_df
from ipynb.fs.full.map_distinct_data import create_distinct_data_map

aws_region = "ap-southeast-2"
schema_name = "fire_data"
table_name ='rfs_fire_data'
result_output_location = "s3://camgoo2-rfs-visualisation/query_results/"
bucket='camgoo2-rfs-visualisation'
athena = boto3.client("athena",region_name=aws_region)

qld_data()
vic_data()
put_to_s3_bucket()

execution_id = query_distinct_data()
df = distinct_data_df()
create_distinct_data_map()
```

Below is my function that I am wanting to import from map_distinct_data notebook. This successfully executes but am getting the error when trying to import to my main page.

```
def query_distinct_data():
    query = "SELECT DISTINCT * from fire_data.rfs_fire_data where state in ('NSW','VIC','QLD')"
    response = athena.start_query_execution(
        QueryString=query,
        ResultConfiguration={"OutputLocation": result_output_location})
    return response["QueryExecutionId"]
```

I am able to run function query_distinct_data() and it executes when run seperately.
But it fails when I try to import the function.

The other functions that I import using ipynb.fs.full that do involve athena are executing okay when imported.

Answer (score 0):

It is all about variables visibility scope ([1](https://www.datacamp.com/tutorial/scope-of-variables-python), [2](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_scope.asp))

In short: `map_distinct_data` module knows nothing about `main page`'s `athena` variable.

#### The good and correct way is to pass `athena` variable inside function as parameter:

```py
from ipynb.fs.full.map_distinct_data import create_distinct_data_map

...
athena = boto3.client("athena",region_name=aws_region)

execution_id = create_distinct_data_map(athena)
```

where `create_distinct_data_map` should be defined as

```py
def create_distinct_data_map(athena):
   ...
```

#### The second way is to set variable inside imported module:

```py
from ipynb.fs.full.map_distinct_data import create_distinct_data_map
from ipynb.fs.full import map_distinct_data

athena = boto3.client("athena",region_name=aws_region)

map_distinct_data.athena = athena

execution_id = create_distinct_data_map()
```

Even if second way is working it is a really bad style.

[Here](https://pynative.com/python-encapsulation/) is some must to know information about encapsulation in Python.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help here. It is now executing.